# AMPscript EMPTY OR NOT EMPTY

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, variable, empty

I have created an AMPscript code for an email where I generate a greeting depends on the variable but I want users who don't have the First Name field to display the Last Name and Salutation and those who have First Name only the First Name appears.

The code is as follows

```
%%[

SET @FirstName = [FirstName] SET @LastName = [LastName]

IF NOT EMPTY(@FirstName) THEN SET @FirstName = CONCAT(@FirstName,) ELSE SET @Salutation = @Salutation

ENDIF

IF Empty(@FirstName) THEN set @LastName = CONCAT("", @LastName,) ELSE Set @Salutation = "" Else

Endif]%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly but based on your description and comments that is what you wanted to do:

```
%%[

VAR @Salutation, @FirstName, @LastName

SET @FirstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")

IF (EMPTY(@FirstName) OR @FirstName == "Unknown") THEN

    SET @LastName = AttributeValue("LastName")
    SET @Salutation = AttributeValue("Salutation")
    
    IF @Salutation == '1' THEN
        SET @Salutation = "Sr"
    ELSEIF @Salutation == '2' THEN
        SET @Salutation = "Sra"
    ELSE
        SET @Salutation = "Sr/Sra"
    ENDIF

ENDIF

]%%
```

It is not clear which variables you are outputting in the end but you can adjust my code to suit your purpose.

Several points regarding your code:

1. No need to have `NOT EMPTY(@FirstName)` if you have checked already with `EMPTY(@FirstName)` and you have there `ELSE` condition;
2. No need to `SET @FirstName = @FirstName`, since if you can check whether it is empty or not, then you should already have a value there inside... thus just leave it as is;
3. Review [Concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat/) function. You were trying to concatenate the variables with no additional values;
4. It is recommended to use `AttributeValue("...")` function rather than simply `SET @FirstName = [FirstName]`

Comment: Your new code does not make much sense. First of all, it does not correlate with the aim you provided and then the main issue is unclear. You are trying to set variables that are already set, creating overlapping conditions and concatenating with a single variable. Please update the aim of the code you are trying to achieve and review the [Concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat/) AMPscript function. After that, I would be able to help.